# sql Вывести название предприятия из другой таблицы имея ключ

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы, в одной заказы(order) в другой сведения о предприятиях(Account), нужно из первой взять максимальную сумму заказов и вывести название предприятия

```
select AccountID from Order group by AccountID 
having sum(amount) >= ALL(
select sum(amount) from Order 
group by AccountID)
```

этот код выводит id предприятия, как его доработать нужно чтобы он вывел его название

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно, сначала объединить обе таблицы, а потом просто сгруппировать и отсортировать. Как то так:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.Account_Name FROM Orders AS o
INNER JOIN Accounts AS a ON o.Account_ID = a.Account_ID
GROUP BY a.Account_Name
ORDER BY SUM(o.Order_Amount) desc
```

[Проверка](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1461c6/10)